# Appending tables vertically

Tags: tables, columns

I have two tables, one for summary statistics and another for balance checks that have the same number of rows and the same variable names for each row.

How can I add the additional column of balance checks results to my existing four summary statistics table? And is there a way to only append the results of the 2nd table without the variable names column?

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! Can you please give a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Currently we have to guess what packages etc you are using and this makes it really hard to help you. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. A MWE makes it much easier to help you both because it will make your question much clearer and because it gives us working code to start from.